# How does android expose Native UI Components to React Native Screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an android application built already that I would like to use React Native in. It's a large application and I don't want to migrate everything at once.

For example, my bottom bar code is a bit complex and I'd like to leave it native for now. For Example: See Picture below

[image]

I want screen partition between android and react native components as

**Bottom bar in Android Native and Updated page content in React Native**

**Note: I have built React Native Bridge and expose android native bottom bar to react environment but they do not show anywhere on screen and it only shows react content.**

Comment: @NimrodArgov yes i have followed integration document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this kind of complexity in this way:

**Before:**

```
    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .addPackage(new OloRNBridgeReactPackage())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .setCurrentActivity(MenuActivity.this)
            .build();

    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "JSMain", null);
   setContentView(mReactRootView);
```

**Result:**

It renders **JSMain** content from React Native only and does not include Android Native Bottom Bar.

**After:**

1. Create android layout xml file **activity_react_footer** and add Android UI Components that you want to include with React Component.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:punchh="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.facebook.react.ReactRootView
        android:id="@+id/react_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Inflate layout in your activity then findViewById ReactRootView with load JS Component and TabLayout also.

   ```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_react_footer);
   mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
           .setApplication(getApplication())
           .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
           .setJSMainModuleName("index")
           .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
           .addPackage(new OloRNBridgeReactPackage())
           .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
           .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
           .setCurrentActivity(MenuActivity.this)
           .build();
   mReactRootView = (ReactRootView) findViewById(R.id.react_root);
   mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "JSMain", null);
   tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
   ```

**Result:**

**This approach will include both contents on screen from Android and React Native. It will solve your problem completely.**

Comment: Can I contact privately to ask you something?